# Regular Expression to identify Cobol EVALUATE block with JAVA

Tags: java, regex, cobol

I want a regular expression to extract text between `EVALUATE` and `END-EVALAUTE or .` which ever comes first.

Presently i am using regular expression:

`EVALUATE\\s*(((?!EVALUATE|(END-EVALUATE|\\.)).)+)\\s*(END-EVALUATE|\\.)`

But my problem is i do not want to consider `.` if it comes within double quotes.

Please suggest any better regular expression or correct the one i have mentioned above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like you need a language parser here, not regex. For every problem you solve, two more will appear if you pursue the regex approach. Regex is a poor choice for parsing languages.

Comment: @Rahul Shouldn't you use context-free grammar for this purpose? You can identify the tokens using regex, then buildup a cfg to parse the code... that's how compilers work.

Comment: No CFG is needed. At least: not for the problem Rahul mentions. A lexer that matches anything between `EVALUATE` and `END-EVALUATE|\.`, where anything is either something other than a quote, or a string literal, can quite easily be done with a regex since there is no recursion.

Comment: Use the compile listing. Depending on the quality/presence, it can do away with any need for constructing a regular expression and can deal with all the problems raised. With IBM Enterprise Cobol it works very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
EVALUATE("[^"]*"|((?!EVALUATE|END-EVALUATE)[^."])+)*(END-EVALUATE|\.)
```

A Java demo:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String src =
                "    EVALUATE WS-ADDITIONAL-FILE-WORK                           \n" +
                "            WHEN \"ACCNT\"                                     \n" +
                "                IF LINK-TRIG-FILE-NAME NOT = \"ACTMSTR   \"    \n" +
                "                PERFORM 04510-GET-ACCOUNT-MASTER               \n" +
                "                ELSE                                           \n" +
                "                MOVE \"0106H\"             TO WS-ERROR-CODE    \n" +
                "                PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR              \n" +
                "                END-IF                                         \n" +
                "             WHEN \"ADDRM\"                                    \n" +
                "                 IF LINK-TRIG-FILE-NAME NOT = \"ADDRMSTR  \"   \n" +
                "                 IF PROGRAM-HBMS-RELEASE (1:3) > \"5.0\"       \n" +
                "                   PERFORM 04520-GET-ADDRESS-MASTER            \n" +
                "                 END-IF                                        \n" +
                "                 ELSE                                          \n" +
                "                   MOVE \"0106H\"        TO WS-ERROR-CODE      \n" +
                "                 PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR             \n" +
                "                 END-IF                                        \n" +
                "             WHEN OTHER                                        \n" +
                "                 MOVE \"0106F\"             TO WS-ERROR-CODE   \n" +
                "                 PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR             \n" +
                "    END-EVALUATE.                                                ";

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("EVALUATE(\"[^\"]*\"|((?!EVALUATE|END-EVALUATE)[^.\"])+)*(END-EVALUATE|\\.)").matcher(src);

        while(m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
EVALUATE WS-ADDITIONAL-FILE-WORK                           
        WHEN "ACCNT"                                     
            IF LINK-TRIG-FILE-NAME NOT = "ACTMSTR   "    
            PERFORM 04510-GET-ACCOUNT-MASTER               
            ELSE                                           
            MOVE "0106H"             TO WS-ERROR-CODE    
            PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR              
            END-IF                                         
        WHEN "ADDRM"                                    
            IF LINK-TRIG-FILE-NAME NOT = "ADDRMSTR  "   
            IF PROGRAM-HBMS-RELEASE (1:3) > "5.0"       
              PERFORM 04520-GET-ADDRESS-MASTER            
            END-IF                                        
            ELSE                                          
              MOVE "0106H"        TO WS-ERROR-CODE      
            PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR             
            END-IF                                        
        WHEN OTHER                                        
            MOVE "0106F"             TO WS-ERROR-CODE   
            PERFORM 09000-PROCESS-ABORT-ERROR             
END-EVALUATE
```

Comment: @Rahul, odd, my regex tester had no problem with it, but indeed, a Java demo threw the same exception. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd point out that the regex given by Bart will match a basic, single-level `EVALUATE` block, however it will NOT cope with *nested* `EVALUATE`s.

For instance, try the regex on the following example:

```
EVALAUTE TRUE
   WHEN FILE-ERROR
      EVALUATE ERROR-CODE
         WHEN FILE-NOT-FOUND
            DISPLAY "File Not Found!"
         WHEN ACCESS-DENIED
            DISPLAY "Access Denied!"
      END-EVALUATE
   WHEN OTHER
      DISPLAY "Success!"
END-EVALUATE
```

Another approach would be to read through the Cobol source line-by-line and for each `EVALUATE` you find on a line (that's not inside quotes), increment an evaluate 'level'. That way you can keep track of where you are in the nested levels.

Also, the OP said he was looking for a way to get the text "**between**" the `EVALUATE` and `END-EVALUATE`, which seems to imply that they should not be included. Maybe I misinterpreted that one, but if that *is* the requirement, then the regex is including the keywords incorrectly.